# Android first window to open

Tags: android, authentication, window

I created a project with Chat.java and activity_main.xml. This is the "window" that opens up. But now I want to change the window, so the login that i wrote (Login.java & LoginXML.xml) appears first. Where do I have to write that? I couldn't find anything :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your activity which you want to load.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

and remove this code from other activity that is loading now.

Comment: Thank you very much! I love Stackoverflow, you guys know everything :D

Comment: But now it throws an error when I try to run it: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':LinkrAndroid:processDebugResources'.
> Running C:\Users\mko\AndroidStudio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aapt.exe failed. See output

Comment: Try clean and build project again and start new AVD. and if problem persist then check your Login file and see whether its working or not?

Answer (score 1):

in Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_label" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

set android:name=".MainActivity_" on your new file

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a splash activity to start the app and then the dashboard activity, something similar to what you want with your login activity and main activity.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DashboardActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

In splash activity I use this code to go to dashboard activity

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Intent dashboardIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(dashboardIntent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

In your case it will be just login logic and then transit to main activity. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh...f***..my R.java is gone? wtf? -.-